# Fibration of hyperbolic 3-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, fibration

A fibration of a manifold $\phi: M \to S^1$ gives rise to a short exact sequence
$$
1 \to \pi_1(N) \to \pi_1(M) = \mathbb{Z} \overset{f_\ast}{\to} 1
$$
where $N$ is the fiber.

I've heard that, if $M$ is a hyperbolic 3-manifold, $\pi_1(N)$ is finitely generated or even finitely presented. Is that true and if so, why?

---

Comment: You do not need hyperbolicity but you should assume compactness. The question itself is more appropriate for Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: Originally posted 1 day ago on math.stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734180/fibration-of-hyperbolic-3-manifold

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true.  Here's one easy construction.  For some $g \geq 2$, let $\Sigma_g$ be a closed oriented genus $g$ surface and let $f\colon \Sigma_g \rightarrow \Sigma_g$ be a homeomorphism representing a pseudo-Anosov mapping class that acts trivially on $H_1(\Sigma_g)$.  There are many constructions of such pseudo-Anosov mapping classes (for example, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0601) paper shows that suitable "random" mapping classes acting trivially on homology are pseudo-Anosov).  For simplicity, isotope $f$ such that it fixes a basepoint.

By Thurston's hyperbolization theorem, the mapping torus $M_f$ is hyperbolic.  Now let $S$ be the universal abelian cover of $\Sigma_g$.  Using the fixed basepoint of $f$, you can lift $f$ to a homeomorphism $\tilde{f}\colon S \rightarrow S$.  The mapping torus $M_{\tilde{f}}$ is then a cover of $M_f$, so it is also hyperbolic.  The associated short exact sequence is
$$1 \longrightarrow \pi_1(S) \longrightarrow \pi_1(M_{\tilde{f}}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 1,$$
and $\pi_1(S)$ is an infinite rank free group.

Answer (score 3):

You are perhaps thinking of Stallings fibration theorem, contained in the paper *On fibering certain 3-manifolds*.  You can find a short discussion of the paper on his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_R._Stallings).